# How to get values of multiple Input fields using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make an Ecommerce website using PHP and AJAX but I am confused at a part. I am facing problem in getting values of all the input fields of the users cart. In other words, say a user have 3 items in their cart and quantity of each item is "1". Now suppose user increases the quantity of the second item in the cart and changes it to "3" and clicked on "Update Cart" button. When update cart is clicked, what I want is to take up just the value which is updated and not the other ones. If that's not possible, I want to take all the values and then update the database accordingly. Currently, when i click on "Update Cart" button, it takes up the quantity value of only the first item in the cart.

The PHP code is below (Please dont mind the variables used)

```
echo "<tr>
        <td class='p-image'>
          <a href='product-details?id=$fetchProductID'><img alt='' src='$theRealLink'></a>
        </td>
        <td class='p-name'><a href='product-details?id=$fetchProductID'>$theName</a></td>
        <td class='p-amount'>INR $fetchProductUnitPrice</td>
        <td class='p-quantity'><input maxlength='100' type='text' value='$fetchProductQuantity' name='quantity' class='productQuantity' data-quant='$fetchProductQuantity'></td>
        <td class='p-total'><span>INR $fetchedProductTotal </span></td>
        <td class='edit'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='delete-from-cart' data-id='$fetchProductID'><img src='assets/img/icon/delte.png' alt=''></a>
        </td>
      </tr>";
```

And the AJAX code is below

```
$('#update-cart').click(function() {
    var quantity = $('.productQuantity').val();
    console.log(quantity);
});
```

Comment: `$('.productQuantity')` will in essence return a set of html items having the class `productQuantity` set, and querying `val()` will only get the value of the firs such element. You would need to iterate over the whole set. see @Patrick Simard 's answer about the "how".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go for updating all of them. You can use the jquery each function for that

```
$(".productQuantity").each(function() {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    console.log(quantity);
    // Get the data-id and build an array so you submit only 1 ajax request
});
```

Comment: it is now running 2 times (because of 2 products in cart) but fetching the quantity of the first product in cart (i.e. its printing 1 , 2 times)

Comment: you need to get the value from the current iterator - try `$(".productQuantity").each(function(idx,elm) { console.log(elm.value); });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure if I'm right in my interpretation, but if you're going to update a value in the database that makes reference to an item in a cart, that means that you need to also identify which item is the one being updated, but I'm not quite seeing that this is clear on the code provided.

Anyway, you could add an event of "onkeyup" on the quantity field and set a flag to the "item" that this quantity belongs to or store it on an array of items to update, and once you press "Update Cart" then just send the modified items to the server.